# valgrind detect fd leak of its own

Tags: valgrind, logfile

I am using valgrind to detect memory leak. However, the valgrind detect fd leak in the program. like the following.

```
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== FILE DESCRIPTORS: 4 open at exit.
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== Open file descriptor 3: client.valgrind(this is open by valgrind)
==00:00:00:40.685 31162==    <inherited from parent>
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== 
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== Open file descriptor 2: /dev/pts/19
==00:00:00:40.685 31162==    <inherited from parent>
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== 
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== Open file descriptor 1: /dev/pts/19
==00:00:00:40.685 31162==    <inherited from parent>
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== 
==00:00:00:40.685 31162== Open file descriptor 0: /dev/pts/19
==00:00:00:40.685 31162==    <inherited from parent>
```

But the client.valgrind is the log file of valgrind and 0 , 1, 2 is standard output input and err file fd. I don't open them apparantly. I feel confused.

Comment: Can you show how you called valgrind?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this should be considered a problem, it's completely normal that valgrind informs you about them. Why should it handle the first 3 fd's in a different way? If you close them (`close(0); close(1); close(2);`) before returning from `main`, these printouts will disappear, but it's clearly unneccessary.